# Allow only certain character in string. Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I have no idea, why this simple code is not working. I am planning to match a string against the allowed pattern.
The string should ONLY have `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` (underscore), `.` (dot) , `-` (hiphen).

Below is code:

```
var profileIDPattern = /[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]./;
var str = 'Heman%t';
console.log('hemant',profileIDPattern.test(str));
```

The code logs 'true' for below string, although these string DOES NOT match the pattern.

```
'Heman%t' -> true
'#Hemant$' -> true
```

I dont know what is the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing it to this RegExp (`/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$/`):

```js
var profileIDPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$/;
var str1 = 'Hemant-._67%'
var str2 = 'Hemant-._67';
console.log('hemant1',profileIDPattern.test(str1));
console.log('hemant2',profileIDPattern.test(str2));
```

Comment: Hey thanks @Arg0n, it worked. Can you please help, what does this * means here. If I am not wrong, then ^ and $ means for start and end of string. I think when I tried last time this type of expression, I have not kept * in it.

Comment: @HemantYadav It means 'zero or more' of the chars inside `[]`. If you want 'one or more' change it to `+`. You are correct about `^` and `$`.

Comment: there is a flaw in your pattern , it will also match empty string , try it `''.test(str1)`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh As stated, if he wants 'one or more' change it to `+`. The question does not mention if empty string is valid or not.

Comment: The question does not mention if empty string is valid or not  , so read this carefully by OP  `I am planning to match a string against the allowed pattern. The string should ONLY have a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _ (underscore), . (dot) , - (hiphen).`

Answer (score 2):

Issues : `[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]` will match any character inside `[]` and `.` will match anything after so basically it will match the mention character and any other character

Use `^` and `$` anchor to mention start and end of match and remove `.`

`^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+` : starting with any given value inside `[]`

`[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$`  : one or more matches and `$` to end the match

```js
var profileIDPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$/;

console.log('hemant',    profileIDPattern.test('Heman%t'));    // no match -
console.log('hemant-._', profileIDPattern.test('hemant-._'));  // valid match
console.log('empty',     profileIDPattern.test(''));           // no match ,empty
```